# Ubuntu 12.10 very slow boot up

Tags: 12.10, boot, boot-failure, startup

I don't know why but when I power up my system Ubuntu starts very slow and after waiting for 15 minutes it only gives me the terminal.. If then I power it down, and turning the computer back on it boots normally.

Here is an example of a normal boot:
http://uppix.net/8/e/f/d16b07381b7cc3473572554211075.png

And this is the unusual boot:
http://uppix.net/9/6/2/8a5dd533046bda79958c6ace8c533.png

Any help on how to fix this?

My system: 2gh centrino 2, 4gb Ram, 9650 Nvidia m GT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that this slowdown is definitely not related directly to Ubuntu Operating system. The problem might be with Hard disk.